# Math operations precision in PHP 5, PHP 7

Tags: php, math, precision

When developing calculator in PHP 5+, can programmer get results without thinking on errors of rounding and imprecise representation of decimal numbers?

I mean built-in perfect ways to get, for example, results with given accuracy.

Or each operation like `$x = $y * $z + 0.77` must require to develop additional checks in algorithm like rounding (for avoiding errors)?

So errors or imprecision - is up to PHP built-in core or up to developer?
PHP 7 has 64-bit support, what is the improvement on this direction (accuracy of calculations)?

Answer (score 1):

> When developing calculator in PHP 5+, can programmer get results without thinking on errors of rounding and imprecise representation of decimal numbers?

Simple answer is `No`.

Doing arithmetics on decimal basis by using a binary machine like a computer can and will always produce some kind of error.

Many details are explained in this article, it's quite a complex subject.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Simple example from the decimal world:

The fraction 1/3 can not be expressed as a finite floating point number in decimal notation. Often we try it by writing `0.333333333...` but that's not 100% accurate.

Same applies to binary number arithmetics.

[Edit]
If you need a very high degree of precision than you should have a look at phps `BC math functions` http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

Comment: Thanks. I tried BC Math for integer calculations. Suppose we have all input data to be known exactly (integer or real). When working with all math functions, is BC Math the best way to get results with minimum errors in PHP? Can we get guaranteed results with N-digit true if we use BC Math?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything in `PHP 7` that will change this. AS @maxhb points out, doing floating point arithmetic is inherently imprecise so you must mind rounding errors.

The 64-bit capability does not fundamentally change this.